# esp-idf calling method from a thread passed by void pointer, incorrect class variable values

Tags: c++, methods, void-pointers, esp-idf

I have a class in my code which has a function that initializes some class variables. Another method in the class can print those variable values. One last method in the class contains a while loop to continuously call the print method, this is the Run method.

Now, the Run method has two methods for doing so. the first is by creating a task (thread) that loops the print method by having the class instance passed as a void *, which I thought is a valid method in xTaskCreate.
Method 2 just calls the function itself in a while loop.

I prefer to know why I have issues when printing the values while being called from a task or thread. In method 1, the values printed are not respectively 1,2,3 but some whole other values as exampled below the code. In method 2, the values are printed as 1,2,3 respectively.

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        void Initialize();
        void Print();
        void Run();

    private:
        uint32_t _valueA;
        uint32_t _valueB;
        uint32_t _valueC;
};

static void execute(void * args) {
    MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(args);
    while(true) {
        myClass->Print();
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}

void MyClass::Initialize() {
    
    _valueA = 1;
    _valueB = 2;
    _valueC = 3;

    printf("a: %lu", _valueA);
    printf("b: %lu", _valueB);
    printf("c: %lu\n", _valueC);
}

void MyClass::Run() {
    //method 1:
    xTaskCreate(execute, "execute", 4096, (void*)this, 1, NULL);

    //method2:
    while(true) {
        Print();
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}

void MyClass::Print() {
    printf("a: %lu", _valueA);
    printf("b: %lu", _valueB);
    printf("c: %lu\n", _valueC);
}

void main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.Initialize();
    myClass.Run();
    
}
```

When using method1, I get printed values for a, b, and c that are not 1,2,3 respectively. But when executing using method 2, I do get 1,2,3 printed respectively.
Output example of method 1:

```
a: 2148598653b: 1073439040c: 1073413228
```

Sure, I could just use method 2 but I would like tasks to work the way I try to implement it. Any suggestions?

I should note that:

- I only run either method1 or method 2
- main is called as extern "C"

Comment: Does `xTaskCreate` create a thread or other asynchronous task?  If so `main` will finish and the local `MyClass myClass;` destroyed, leaving `execute` with a dangling pointer.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense. I'm not sure which of the two it creates but I think main will finish. Let me test

Comment: Long live pointers. You were completely right! the MyClass object was destroyed since xTraskCreate returns after it created the task and then so dus myClass.Run() finish. the myClass object is then destroyed. thank you so much. If you create a post I can give you an upvote and solution flag